# MongoDB: how to create a local "full" database backup from different remote snapshots with DB Compass

Tags: mongodb, nosql, backup, mongodb-compass

I have the following scenario:

- a free Mongo-DB hosted on Atlas (mongodb.com)
- the storage size is restricted to 500 MB
- a personal app stores values into this DB

But within serveral weeks, the DB reaches the file size limit.
At the moment and without better knowing, I can create a local DB copy of the complete Database (using No-SQL-Booster) and delete all the old data in the remote DB to reduce the remote file size.

I am looking for a way to export all new remote data into one big local DB to have all historic data together in one DB.

Coming from the "old" MySQL world, I am afraid of not being able to a simple insert because of referential integrity, although I know that this is not an issue in nosql-databases.

As I am new to nosql, I would like to ask for your kind support: how can I export all data in all collections of the remote Atlas-DB?
As far as I see, Mongo DB Compass does not support direkt "copy & paste" of databses or collections between remote and local servers.

Is there a kind of script that does the job automatically? Just something like...

- get all collections in the remote db
- copy all new data from all these collections into the local db (do not delete anything, just create/insert everything that is not in the db yet!)

I hope that this is not a big thing, but I did not find anything that fits my needs yet..
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at `mongoimport/mongoexport` and `mongodump/mongorestore`, see [MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/)

Comment: Thank you, of course I've read the docs. But it does not answer how to integrate the "new parts" of the export into the local db with all historic data.

Comment: If you don't use the --drop option with the restore it will write the data from the backup in the existing collection/database.

Comment: Thanks @Joe - so you mean: 
1) mongoexport the remote collections into a file
2) restore that backupfile into the local collections.   Maybe you can tell me the syntax of the code that does the job (export and restore ALL collections)?

Comment: There are examples in the mongodump and mongorestore sections of the doc that WernfriedDomscheit linked above

Comment: Using NoSQL Booster, I can copy the full database without using a shell. Now I'm trying to merge all local databases into one, but I'm not which insertion strategy I should use: "overwrite documents with same id" (no!) - "always insert with new id (faster)" (maybe? sounds good, if there are no data integrity problems - "insert with new _id if _id exists" (why not, same as above) - "skip documents with existing _id" (I chose this option, being scared of crashing the db) - abort if _id already exists (no option for me). Which one should I use? (a lot _ids already exist!)